Tab highlight in IntelliJ terminal stopped working
I am on MacBook and using ZSH with iTerm2.
On iTerm, when typing any command, if I press TAB key, I can highlight the selections as shown in this question. This feature was working in IntelliJ until recently. But now it stopped working. I am using below IDE.
IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-241.15989.150, built on April 29, 2024

Has anybody observed this behavior?

Were there any changes made recently? Any new plugin enabled?

Not really! I tried to reinstall the IntelliJ w/o any external plugins. That didn't help.

This requires log reviewing to check further
